# Firebase functions environment variables not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables

I have `test.env` file in my functions folder.

`test.env`

```
 TEST="TEST NAME"
```

And in my functions I have:

```
app.get("/testvars", (req, res) => {
    console.log("ENV", process.env.TEST);
});
```

I then run `firebase serve`, which logs `ENV undefined` when invoked

Why is this not working?

And I am using firebase-functions `3.23.0` with `11.8.0` firebase cli

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rename your file from `test.env` to just `.env` (starting with a dot).

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#env-variables

If you are having a [project alias named `test`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#deploying_multiple_sets_of_environment_variables) then you should put the project id/alias **after** `.env` (`.env.test`).

Comment: This is not working in firebase for me, after switching with `firebase use ${alias}`, the deployed environment always uses whatever is in `.env` and does not get overridden with the `.env.${alias}` file instead